# scenario outline cucumber typescript

Tags: playwright-typescript

Iam searching how can i implement the cucumber scenario outline in typescript,
How can I click on 3 different inputs using typescript and playwright cucumber ?

This is the scenario and typescript implementation but it doesn't work

`Scenario: test multiClicks
Given test displayed
When I click ''
Then I should see all captures

```
        | header1  |
        | input2   |
        | input3   |
        | input4    |`
```

My implementation

what is wrong here

`When('I click {string}', async function (header1: string) { const page = this.page!; await page.click("text=" + header1); });`

thankyou !

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you got this fixed but if you pasted your Scenario exactly as you have it then you are missing some syntax and it should look like below.

```
    Scenario: test multiClicks 
    Given test displayed 
    When I click '<header1>' 
    Then I should see all captures

    | header1   |
    | input2    |
    | input3    |
    | input4    |
```

Then also, I think you want to follow the click pattern more like:
await page.getByRole('button', { name: header1 }).click();

Comment: Thankyou, 
this is what i am searching !